# IIS 7.5 Powershell script - Management service & Configure Web Deploy Publishing

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, webdeploy

I am creating a script to automate an IIS install on server 2012,

having the script near completed I can't find any information on the following two topics:
- Management Service
- Configure Web Deploy Publishing

Specifically within management service I am looking to set an IP automatically using a pre-set parameter within my script ,is this possible? Any forums/articles I have read have yet to mention this area within powershell

Secondly within Configure Web Deploy Publishing, I am looking to change the default username, again using a pre-set parameter within my script.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be perfect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

About the IIS Management Service, I looked at my own server setup scripts which are a few years old and not exclusively PowerShell:

It seems there are two registry locations you need to change, here's part of my script:

```
sc.exe config wmsvc start= delayed-auto
reg.exe add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server /v EnableRemoteManagement /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
net start wmsvc
```

In the same registry key there is a Reg_SZ `IPAddress` which you can set.

There is also:
   `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\http\parameters\SslBindingInfo\0.0.0.0:8172`

you need to have a new key with your own IP, rather than doing this manually, you should use netsh instead:

```
$thumb = (ls cert:\LocalMachine\MY | where-object { $_.FriendlyName -like "*WMSvc*" } | Select-Object -First 1).Thumbprint
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid()

& netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8172
& netsh http add sslcert ipport=192.168.10.10:8172 certhash=$thumb appid=`{$guid`}
```

I haven't tested this because I never had to change the default 0.0.0.0, but I expect this should work.

Comment: Thanks  Sam, I had a quick look at the registry:
REG_S: IPADDRESS, is within the connections  field , I should have mentioned I am looking it to autofill "IP Address Restrictions" either to allow or deny an IP address connecting externally.